# Loading resource files within a jar

Tags: java, jar, io, loading

What's the best way to load resources (Sounds, images, xml data), that also works from inside a distributed jar file?

I need to load some sounds, images, and xml data, for use in my program. Using

```
AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(new File("~/src/com/example/package/name/assets/TestSound.wav"));
```

does not work in the jar, for obvious reasons, including the fact that `src` will not be in the jar.

**Edit:**

(A working) MWE: http://pastebin.com/CNq6zgPw

Comment: You need to give the path as it's in the jar not as it appear in your project. If you have it in a package directory then it should be something like /package/name/assets/TestSound.wav.

Comment: @Eranda That's the code that is used in the IDE (Eclipse Luna) to load it.
The root folder is put at the project root, which also has the /bin/ and /src/ folders.

Comment: Can you extract the jar which contain your TestSound.wav and paste the structure of it to the question please so that I can give you a direct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet of code worked for me:

```
Clip clip = null;
ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader();
AudioInputStream ais;
URL url = cl.getResource("com/example/project/assets/TestSound.wav");
System.out.println(url);
try {
    ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(url);
clip = AudioSystem.getClip();
clip.open(ais);
}
catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
}
```

The important thing is not adding the `/src/` folder to the class path.

The critical change is changing `cl.getResource("/com/example/project/assets/TestSound.wav")` to `cl.getResource("com/example/project/assets/TestSound.wav");`
because `/com/...` indicates that the path is absolute, whereas `com/...` indicates that the path is relative.

For example,

```
System.out.println(new File("/Test.File").getAbsolutePath());
System.out.println(new File("Test.File").getAbsolutePath());
```

return

```
/Test.File
/Users/alphadelta/Documents/Workspace/TestProject/Test.File
```

respectively.

The first File created is created using `"/Test.File"`, which is absolute. The second is created using `"Test.File"`, which is relative to the project root in eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

The `ClassLoader` class has two relevant methods:

- `getResource(path)` delivers a URL for any resource on the classpath,
- `getResourceAsStream(path)` delivers an input stream for the resource.

You can use these methods with overloads of the `AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(...)` method to get an audio stream that reads a resource in your JAR file.

---

Note that if you call these methods on a `ClassLoader` object, that paths will be resolved in the namespaces of the JAR files on the classpath ... not the filesystem namespace of your development platform.

Comment: So...

The path "/package/name/assets/sound/TestSound.wav" will work in the context of the jar. Is there a way that I can get it to work in Eclipse too? Or do I have to modify the classes that use the resources and change the paths to work inside the jar?

Comment: Assuming that the directory structure is as described in your updated question, you should add the `src` directory.

Comment: Hmm... That did not work. By class path, do you mean the java build path?

I keep getting a NPE because `getResource()` is returning `null`.

MWE: http://pastebin.com/ZdGH7kru

Comment: No.  I mean the runtime / execution classpath.  http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Ftasks%2Ftasks-java-local-configuration.htm

Comment: Ah. Thanks. It works now. Apparently you also have to change `/com/package/...` to `com/package/...`.
MWE: http://pastebin.com/CNq6zgPw

Comment: That's odd. Removing the folder `/src/` from the classpath did not affect the  code. 
I guess it was the change of `/com/...` to `com/`

Answer (score 1):

You can load any resources using this code from the jar or outside of the jar:

```
InputStream is = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("~/src/package/name/assets/TestSound.wav");
```